# Index of nilpotency Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, block-matrices, nilpotence

If $T$ is an endomorphism, there exists a basis, according to which $T$ will be a block-diagonal matrix. Because if $V$ is the domain of $T$, $V$ will be the direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces, so we can choose a basis in each generalized eigenspace and extends to a basis of $V$, according to which $T$ will indeed be a block-diagonal matrix.

Every block of this matrix can be written as the sum of a multiple of the identity matrix (the multiple is an eigenvalue and the size of the identity matrix conforms with the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue) and a matrix $N$, which is nilpotent with some index $s$.

Now the claim is:

"The order of nilpotency of $N$ equals the multiplicity of the according eigenvalue in the minimal polynomial of the endomorphism $T$".

(This claim has been made in the beginning of a chapter of Jordan-block matrices, but I don't think this is the Jordan-block matrix already).
I hope my question is clear and someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that is enough to consider the case when $V$ is the generalized eigenspace relative to a single eigenvalue $\alpha$.

$N$ can represented as a [Jordan matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix), a blockwise diagonal matrix, with blocks that are Jordan blocks relative to the eigenvalue $0$.

A Jordan block relative to the eigenvalue zero is nilpotent. Then it corresponds to a  linear mapping that maps $e_1 \mapsto e_2 \mapsto \dots \mapsto e_n \mapsto 0$, where the $e_i$ are suitably chosen independent vectors. It is not difficult to see that this has nilpotence index $n$.

Now if the Jordan blocks of $N$ have size $n_1 \le n_2 \le \dots \le n_k$, clearly $N^{n_k} = 0$, and $N^{n_k - 1} \ne 0$, so the nilpotence index is $n_k$. But then $T = \alpha I + N$ has minimal polynomial $(x-\alpha)^{n_k}$, because it is a root of it, but not of $(x-\alpha)^{n_k-1}$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I see now that I completely messed up in formulating the question. I edited my post, reformulating.

Comment: OK, I see now. I will be rewriting my answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, done, please check whether it is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very clear. But i still have a problem though with generalizing this, when the domain of T is V, and not a generalized eigenspace. Am I right, when i say that in fact not the minimal polynomial of T is $(x-\alpha)^{n_k}$, but the minimal polynomial of T restricted to the eigenspace of $\alpha?$ I feel that the minimal polynomial of T will be the product of all those minimal polynomials, but it seems i'm not able to prove it.

Comment: It is. Note that $(x-\alpha)^n$ is coprime with $(x - \beta)^m$ for $\alpha \ne \beta$, and then note that if the minimal polynomial of $T$ is the product of two coprime polynomials $f, g$, then $V = \ker(f(T)) \oplus \ker(g(T))$.

Comment: Aha, i understand it now :D. Thank you for your effort!